# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin(\frac{x}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^n \sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly on every finite interval.

At first thought, I try to find a bound, $M_n$, for the sine term such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M_n < \infty$.

However, the best I can find is that $\sin(\frac x n) \leq \frac R n + \frac{1}{n^3}$  for $x \in [-R,R]$

And now, I totally don't know how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $\sin(y)$ gives $|\sin(\frac{x}{n})-\frac{x}{n}| < \frac{|x|}{n^3}$ for $|x/n| < \pi/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that, by a Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$, we have
$$
\sin u= u+O(u^3)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sin \frac{x}{n}= \frac{x}{n}+O_x\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
$$ and, for any $N\ge1, M \ge1,$
$$
\sum_{n=N}^M(-1)^n\sin \frac{x}{n}=x \cdot \sum_{n=N}^M\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sum_{n=N}^M O_x\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
$$ one may deduce that
$$
\left|\sum_{n=N}^M(-1)^n\sin \frac{x}{n}\right|\le |x| \cdot\left|\sum_{n=N}^M\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|+\sum_{n=N}^M\left|O_x\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right|
$$  which yields the *uniform convergence* of the given series over each compact set $[-R,R]$, $R>0$.

Comment: I don't think this is right. You've shown the partial sums of the series are uniformly bounded, but that does not prove uniform convergence, or even pointwise convergence. For example, $|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n|\le 1$ for all $N.$

Comment: @zhw You are right. But the path I've taken above works *not only* on partial sums but *also* on remainders, I've then edited my answer, thus the expected conclusion holds. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You have shown the series is pointwise Cauchy, but $\mathcal{O}_x$ is not very clear. Why don't you assume $x \in [- R,R]$ at the beginning ? (and consider $n$ large enough, that is $|x/n| < \pi /2$)

Comment: Sure we have the pointwise convergence, but taking $\sup$ over $[-R,R]$ of both sides of the latter inequality, gives the *uniform* convergence on the given set.

Comment: But you still have this $O_x$ business. You need a uniform $O(1/n^3).$

Comment: Please, are you unaware that this $\left|\mathcal{O_x}\right|$ is uniformly bounded over $|x| \leq R$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $b>0.$ We'll show uniform convergence on $[-b,b].$ Because the terms of the series are odd, it's enough to prove uniform convergence on $[0,b].$

Let $0<\epsilon< \pi/2.$ Choose $N$ such that $b/N < \epsilon.$ Note that the sequence $\sin (x/N), \sin (x/(N+1)), \sin (x/(N+2)),\dots$ is then decreasing for each $x\in [0,b].$

Suppose $N\le m <n.$ Claim:

$$\tag 1 |\sum_{k=m}^{n}(-1)^n\sin (x/k)| <\epsilon \text { for } x\in [0,b].$$

Proof: The terms in this series decrease in absolute value and are alternating in sign. Therefore $(1)$ is no larger than $|\sin(x/m)|\le |x/m| \le b/m\le b/N < \epsilon.$ This proves the claim.

Note that the claim says precisely that the partial sums of our series are uniformly Cauchy on $[0,b].$ Hence the series converges uniformly on $[0,b].$